# On mac library cairo and libcairo-2 not found when trying to use graphviz

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, graphviz

I face challenges when using **Graphviz** (on Mac M2). I am having an error displayed.

I want to be able to use the library without having an error in return. Any tips?

This is the terminal section where I have executed some commands,
**terminal:**

```
# python3 --version
# Python 3.11.2


#brew install graphviz  // (Cairo etc are installed along)
# dot -V                                      
# dot - graphviz version 8.1.0 (20230707.0739)
# which dot                                   
# /opt/homebrew/bin/dot
# echo $PATH | tr : ' ' | fmt -w1 | grep local
# /usr/local/bin
```

This is the file that contains the code related to graphviz,
**task.ipynb:**

```
graphviz_path = '/opt/homebrew/bin/dot'
# graphviz_path = '/usr/local/bin'

import os
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + graphviz_path

from graphviz import Source
from sklearn import tree
graph = Source( tree.export_graphviz(dtc_model, out_file=None, feature_names=features.columns))

from cairosvg import svg2png

from IPython.display import Image
svg2png(bytestring=graph.pipe(format='svg'),write_to='output.png')
Image("output.png")
```

This is the error displayed when I am running the script,**error:**

```
--> 1 from cairosvg import svg2png
      3 from IPython.display import Image
      4 svg2png(bytestring=graph.pipe(format='svg'),write_to='output.png')

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cairosvg/__init__.py:26
     22 VERSION = __version__ = (ROOT / 'VERSION').read_text().strip()
     25 # VERSION is used in the "url" module imported by "surface"
---> 26 from . import surface  # noqa isort:skip
     29 SURFACES = {
     30     'PDF': surface.PDFSurface,
     31     'PNG': surface.PNGSurface,
   (...)
     34     'SVG': surface.SVGSurface,
     35 }
     38 def svg2svg(bytestring=None, *, file_obj=None, url=None, dpi=96,
     39             parent_width=None, parent_height=None, scale=1, unsafe=False,
     40             background_color=None, negate_colors=False, invert_images=False,
     41             write_to=None, output_width=None, output_height=None):

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cairosvg/surface.py:9
      6 import copy
      7 import io
...
no library called "cairo" was found
no library called "libcairo-2" was found
cannot load library 'libcairo.so.2': dlopen(libcairo.so.2, 0x0002): tried: 'libcairo.so.2' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OSlibcairo.so.2' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libcairo.so.2' (no such file, not in dyld cache), 'libcairo.so.2' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libcairo.so.2' (no such file, not in dyld cache).  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'libcairo.so.2'
cannot load library 'libcairo.2.dylib': dlopen(libcairo.2.dylib, 0x0002): tried: 'libcairo.2.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OSlibcairo.2.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libcairo.2.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache), 'libcairo.2.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libcairo.2.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache).  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'libcairo.2.dylib'
cannot load library 'libcairo-2.dll': dlopen(libcairo-2.dll, 0x0002): tried: 'libcairo-2.dll' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OSlibcairo-2.dll' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libcairo-2.dll' (no such file, not in dyld cache), 'libcairo-2.dll' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libcairo-2.dll' (no such file, not in dyld cache).  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'libcairo-2.dll'
```

Answer (score 1):

You must install cairo with Homebrew,

```
brew install cairo
```

After this, I still got the error. I had to locate the installed files,

```
brew list cairo
```

Then I manually copied the needed library to a location in my path:

```
cp /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cairo/1.16.0_5/lib/libcairo.2.dylib /usr/local/lib
```

After this, I could import cairosvg.